# What should be in the tag (graph)?

Tags: discussion, tagging

> **NOTE** The (graph) tag is dead. Long live the graph...ing-functions tag. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9051/1543).

At the moment, there is a [discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8729/lets-blacklist-the-graph-tag) about the tag [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph); the suggestion is to replace it with a better name, so that the questions from graph-theory are not tagged by this tag.

In the comments we came also to the questions what should be the content of this tag (or its replacement). The [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) at the moment says:

> Questions regarding graphs of functions. Questions about graphs with vertices and edges should use the (graph-theory) tag instead.

This sounds (at least to me) as if this tag could be used for any question where the notion of the graph of the function is relevant. However in [some of the comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8729/lets-blacklist-the-graph-tag#comment29883_8729) it was suggested, that this tag is only for questions about plotting graphs of functions and the "basic stuff" concerning graphs. (I am not able to define more precisely what I mean by basic stuff, let us just say that this includes only things not trespassing into more advanced teritory, such as real analysis, general topology, functional analysis.) Probably many MSE users use this tag only in this sense.

But there are also questions tagged [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph), where this tag is used in broader sense, such as:

- [Does Closed Graph imply Closed Range](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326902/does-closed-graph-imply-closed-range)
- [$f:M_1\to M_2$ is continuous iff its graph is compact.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304601/fm-1-to-m-2-is-continuous-iff-its-graph-is-compact)

---

I think it would be good if we could agree on the meaning of the tag and edit the tag-excerpt/tag-wiki accordingly, so that they can serve as a guide when tagging a question.

---

**EDIT:** The tag graph has been blacklisted and the questions have been moved to a new tag named [graphing-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphing-functions). The new name for the tag is definitely not for questions about graphs of functions in general (as in the examples given above). So I consider this discussion resolved and I have accepted the more special answer.

Comment: As an aside: I wrote that tag-excerpt way-back-when for the purpose of disambiguation; so the intent was _exclusive_ ((graph-theory) does not go here) as opposed to _inclusive_ (anything that is not (graph-theory) goes here). So please don't read too much into the existing tag-wiki in this case.

Comment: What about having 2 tags: graph, and graphing, with whatever clear description of the tags? I did not read the other discussion, and apologize if this was already suggested.

Comment: @gnome: the other discussion wants to kill the (graph) tag completely, so I'd say what you suggested is rather orthogonal to the intention there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upvote this post if you think that the tag [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) should include only questions about plotting graphs and similar basic stuff related to graphs of functions.

If you disagree, then downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Please upvote this post if you thing that the tag [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) should contain also more advanced stuff and most things that are concerned with graphs of functions.

If you disagree, then downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples of the post that are currently tagged [graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph) and this tag is used in the "broader sense". (So they might need retagging, if the consensus is that this tag is for questions about plotting graphs of functions.)

- [lower semicontinuity and closed graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268206/lower-semicontinuity-and-closed-graph)
- [$f:M_1\to M_2$ is continuous iff its graph is compact.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304601/fm-1-to-m-2-is-continuous-iff-its-graph-is-compact)
- [Does Closed Graph imply Closed Range](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326902/does-closed-graph-imply-closed-range)
- [Operator Graph Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342007/operator-graph-question)

Comment: I have already retagged those question - when the tag [tag:graph] was going to be renamed [tag:graphing-functions]. The name (graphing-functions) was the most upvoted from the alternative and it suggests that the tag should be used only in the stricter sense. If you disagree with this and think that it should include the questions as above, this question is the ideal place to voice your opinion.